# How to use "KERNEL_SIZE" in a Google Earth Engine code?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, function

I found online the code below ([Source of the code](https://github.com/adugnag/gee_s1_ard/blob/main/javascript/speckle_filter.js)). I would like to implement it but I don't understand what "KERNEL_SIZE" means. When I run the script as it is now, I get the error "Parameter 'radius' is required". Can anyone explain to me how the code works? The image input is an image collection of Sentinel-1.

```
function LeeFilter(image, KERNEL_SIZE) {
    var bandNames = image.bandNames().remove('angle');
    //S1-GRD images are multilooked 5 times in range
    var enl = 5
    // Compute the speckle standard deviation
    var eta = 1.0/Math.sqrt(enl); 
    eta = ee.Image.constant(eta);

    // MMSE estimator
    // Neighbourhood mean and variance
    var oneImg = ee.Image.constant(1);

    var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
                  reducer2: ee.Reducer.variance(),
                  sharedInputs: true
                  });
    var stats = image.select(bandNames).reduceNeighborhood({reducer: reducers,kernel: ee.Kernel.square(KERNEL_SIZE/2,'pixels'), optimization: 'window'})
    var meanBand = bandNames.map(function(bandName){return ee.String(bandName).cat('_mean')});
    var varBand = bandNames.map(function(bandName){return ee.String(bandName).cat('_variance')});
    
    var z_bar = stats.select(meanBand);
    var varz = stats.select(varBand);

    // Estimate weight 
    var varx = (varz.subtract(z_bar.pow(2).multiply(eta.pow(2)))).divide(oneImg.add(eta.pow(2)));
    var b = varx.divide(varz);

    //if b is negative set it to zero
    var new_b = b.where(b.lt(0), 0)
    var output = oneImg.subtract(new_b).multiply(z_bar.abs()).add(new_b.multiply(image.select(bandNames)));
    output = output.rename(bandNames);
    return image.addBands(output, null, true);
}   

var s1_lee = s1.map(LeeFilter); 

Map.addLayer(s1_lee, vis,'Lee Filter');
```

[Full script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3ee1a34cafa3fae63f6993d6dcc142c2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is a missing value (i.e., radius) when applying the `ee.Kernel.square` function, so that means that the `KERNEL_SIZE` variable does not have an assigned value. Here, you can do two alternatives to avoid the error:

1. Remove the `KERNEL_SIZE` argument from the LeeFilter function and set it inside the function. This alternative might be the easier to use if the `KERNEL_SIZE` corresponds to a constant value.

   ```
    var LeeFilter = function(image) 
        {
          var KERNEL_SIZE = 5;
          var bandNames = image.bandNames().remove('angle');
          //S1-GRD images are multilooked 5 times in range
          var enl = 5
          // Compute the speckle standard deviation
          var eta = 1.0/Math.sqrt(enl); 
          eta = ee.Image.constant(eta);

          // MMSE estimator
          // Neighbourhood mean and variance
          var oneImg = ee.Image.constant(1);

          var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
                      reducer2: ee.Reducer.variance(),
                      sharedInputs: true
                      });
          var stats = image.select(bandNames).reduceNeighborhood({reducer: reducers,kernel: ee.Kernel.square(KERNEL_SIZE/2,'pixels'), optimization: 'window'})
          var meanBand = bandNames.map(function(bandName){return ee.String(bandName).cat('_mean')});
          var varBand = bandNames.map(function(bandName){return ee.String(bandName).cat('_variance')});

          var z_bar = stats.select(meanBand);
          var varz = stats.select(varBand);

          // Estimate weight 
          var varx = (varz.subtract(z_bar.pow(2).multiply(eta.pow(2)))).divide(oneImg.add(eta.pow(2)));
          var b = varx.divide(varz);

          //if b is negative set it to zero
          var new_b = b.where(b.lt(0), 0)
          var output = oneImg.subtract(new_b).multiply(z_bar.abs()).add(new_b.multiply(image.select(bandNames)));
          output = output.rename(bandNames);
          return image.addBands(output, null, true);
        }
   ```
2. Use a wrapper function to be able to pass a `KERNEL_SIZE` argument, since mapped functions cannot take more than one argument (by default, this single argument is each entry inside the collection over which the mapped function is being passed). This way, you can pass the `KERNEL_SIZE` value when using the `wrapper` function.

   ```
    var wrapper = function(KERNEL_SIZE)
      {
        var LeeFilter = function(image) 
          {
            var bandNames = image.bandNames().remove('angle');
            //S1-GRD images are multilooked 5 times in range
            var enl = 5
            // Compute the speckle standard deviation
            var eta = 1.0/Math.sqrt(enl); 
            eta = ee.Image.constant(eta);

            // MMSE estimator
            // Neighbourhood mean and variance
            var oneImg = ee.Image.constant(1);

            var reducers = ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
                      reducer2: ee.Reducer.variance(),
                      sharedInputs: true
                      });
            var stats = image.select(bandNames).reduceNeighborhood({reducer: reducers,kernel: ee.Kernel.square(KERNEL_SIZE/2,'pixels'), optimization: 'window'})
            var meanBand = bandNames.map(function(bandName){return ee.String(bandName).cat('_mean')});
            var varBand = bandNames.map(function(bandName){return ee.String(bandName).cat('_variance')});

            var z_bar = stats.select(meanBand);
            var varz = stats.select(varBand);

            // Estimate weight 
            var varx = (varz.subtract(z_bar.pow(2).multiply(eta.pow(2)))).divide(oneImg.add(eta.pow(2)));
            var b = varx.divide(varz);

            //if b is negative set it to zero
            var new_b = b.where(b.lt(0), 0)
            var output = oneImg.subtract(new_b).multiply(z_bar.abs()).add(new_b.multiply(image.select(bandNames)));
            output = output.rename(bandNames);
            return image.addBands(output, null, true);
          } ;
      return LeeFilter;
      };


    var s1_lee = s1.map(wrapper(5));
   ```